# Installing Gazebo from source on Ubuntu 14.04 : Unable to locate package libqwt-qt5-dev

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install Gazebo from source on Ubuntu 14.04 (would wish to be on 16.04 but I unfortunately need another library for my project which is only supported on 14.04...).

So I followed the procedure found here : http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_from_source&ver=default

and while installing the dependencies, at step 3 "Install prerequisites", got this message error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libqwt-qt5-dev
```

I understand I don't have libqwt-qt5-dev, but when trying to install it :

```
sudo apt-get install libqwt-qt5-dev
```

I get :

```
E: Unable to locate package libqwt-qt5-dev
```

Not sure, but looking at this, it seems that the library has no package for 14.04 : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqwt-qt5-dev

So... my question would be what is the most recent version of Gazebo to use in 14.04 and how to install it from source? Even when I change the Gazebo version in the tutorial, I get the same procedure (or maybe I do not see the difference).

Thanks in advance, any help is really appreciated.

Regards,

David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15633/installing-gazebo-from-source-on-ubuntu-14.04-:-unable-to-locate-package-libqwt-qt5-dev/) by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Finally, I found out what was my problem. In [this Gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_from_source&ver=7.0) (this links to the Gazebo 7 version of the tutorial as Gazebo 7 is the last version available on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty), the first steps are the following :

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/osrf/release-tools/raw/default/jenkins-scripts/lib/dependencies_archive.sh -O /tmp/dependencies.sh
ROS_DISTRO=dummy . /tmp/dependencies.sh
sudo apt-get install $(sed 's:\\ ::g' <<< $GAZEBO_BASE_DEPENDENCIES) $(sed 's:\\ ::g' <<< $BASE_DEPENDENCIES)
```

So I looked at the file **/tmp/dependencies.sh** in gedit and found out that I need to specify **GAZEBO_MAJOR_VERSION=7** prior to running the script so that it does not look for libqwt-qt5-dev. So here is what I suggest to those trying to build Gazebo from source on Ubuntu 14.04. When installing the dependencies at the begining of the procedure in the tutorial, do the following instead :

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/osrf/release-tools/raw/default/jenkins-scripts/lib/dependencies_archive.sh -O /tmp/dependencies.sh
ROS_DISTRO=dummy GAZEBO_MAJOR_VERSION=7 DISTRO=trusty . /tmp/dependencies.sh
sudo apt-get install $(sed 's:\\ ::g' <<< $GAZEBO_BASE_DEPENDENCIES) $(sed 's:\\ ::g' <<< $BASE_DEPENDENCIES)
```

Just added **GAZEBO_MAJOR_VERSION=7 DISTRO=trusty** to the second command line.

Then, building Gazebo from source (using gazebo7 branch) worked fine.

---

Originally posted by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) with karma: 38 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We dropped Trusty in Gazebo 8. The most recent version that you should be able to install from source or debs in Ubuntu Trusty is Gazebo 7 (branch gazebo7 on the repository). Make sure to remove your build directory before recompiling just in case.

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2017-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) on 2017-03-22**:
Thanks for answering. I agree about Gazebo 7 being the last version for Trusty. Then where can I find the installation procedure for the dependencies of gazebo (not having cloned gazebo yet) so that it does not asks for libqwt-qt5-dev? Because these are deb packages and I don't know how to specify a version if that is possible. I suppose I can install gazebo 7 without that library somehow if. Right?

**Comment by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) on 2017-03-22**:
"Because these are deb packages and I don't know how to specify a version if that is possible."

By that I meant : is there a different prompt command than

wget https://bitbucket.org/osrf/release-tools/raw/default/jenkins-scripts/lib/dependencies_archive.sh -O /tmp/dependencies.sh

ROS_DISTRO=dummy . /tmp/dependencies.sh

sudo apt-get install $(sed 's:\\ ::g' <<< $BASE_DEPENDENCIES) $(sed 's:\\ ::g' <<< $GAZEBO_BASE_DEPENDENCIES)

That last line is where I am stucked. Thanks again for your help

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2017-03-23**:
The gazebo7 branch on https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo will not depend on libqwt-qt5-dev. If you want to install gazebo from source, you'll need to clone the repository and update to the gazebo7 branch. Then try cmake, make, make install.

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2017-03-23**:
if you're building from source and don't mind using gazebo without the plotting tool then you can try modifying gazebo to make qwt an optional dependency. Changes in this commit should help: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/commits/5428a4549406c64db413caf3b799cd5641fae07d

**Comment by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) on 2017-03-27**:
Thanks for your help, The link on bitbucket does not seem to work when I try to load it. However, I finally found a way to build gazebo on my own and I made a new answer to explain what I did. If you have any comment on that answer, feel free to do so. Thanks again!